# Spark (Scala) execute dataframe within for loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 1.6.1 version. I have requirement to execute dataframe in loop.

```
for ( i <- List ('a','b')){
 val i = sqlContext.sql("SELECT i, col1, col2 FROM DF1")}
```

I want this dataframe to be executed twice (`i = a` and `i = b`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. 
Except two things :

- `i` is already used in your `for` loop so don't use it in `val i =`
- If you want to use the value of `i` in a string, use String Interpolation

So your code should look like :

```
for (i <- List ('a','b')) {
  val df = sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT $i, col1, col2 FROM DF1")
  df.show()
}
```

---

**EDIT after author comment :**

You can do this with a `.map` and then a `.reduceLeft` :

```
// All your dataframes
val dfs = Seq('a','b').map { i =>
  sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT $i, col1, col2 FROM DF1")
}

// Then you can reduce your dataframes into one
val unionDF = dfs.reduceLeft((dfa, dfb) => 
  dfa.unionAll(dfb)
)
```

Comment: Actually I need different dataframes (in this case 2, a and b).

Suppose if DF1 contains below data -
col1,col2
1,A
2,B

Then dataframe **a** should contains :-
a,1,A
a,2,B

and dataframe **b** should contain :-

b,1,A
b,2,B

I have to create 30 odd similiar kind of dataframes and then union them all.

Comment: Perfect! It's working now.

Only little tweak I made is ** s"${'"'}$i${'"'}" ** to accommodate quotes for string.