# How to efficiently perform nested-loop in Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory, apache-spark-sql

So I have this main dataframe, called `main_DF` which contain all measurement values:

```
main_DF
group    index   width    height
--------------------------------
1        1       21.3       15.2
1        2       11.3       45.1
2        3       23.2       25.2
2        4       26.1       85.3
...
23       986453  26.1       85.3
```

And another table called `selected_DF`, derived from `main_DF`, which contain the start & end index of important rows in `main_DF`, along with the length (`end_index - start_index`). The fields `start_index` and `end_index` correspond with field `index` in `main_DF`.

```
selected_DF
group    start_index   end_index    length
--------------------------------
1        1             154          153
2        236           312          76
3        487           624          137
...
238      17487         18624        1137
```

Now, for each row in `selected_DF`, I need to perform filtering for all measurement values between the `start_index` and `end_index`. For example, let's say row 1 is for `index` = 1 until 154. After some filtering, dataframe derived from this row is:

```
peak_DF
peak_start   peak_end
--------------------------------
1            12
15           21
27           54
86           91
...
143          150
```

`peak_start` and `peak_end` indicate the area where `width` exceeds the threshold. It was obtained by selecting all `width > threshold`, and then check the position of its `index` (sorry but it's kind of hard to explain, even with the code)

Then I need to take the measurement value (`width`) based on `peak_DF` and calculate the average, making it something like:

```
peak_DF_summary
peak_start   peak_end    avg_width
--------------------------------
1            12          25.6
15           21          35.7
27           54          24.2
86           91          76.6
...
143          150         13.1
```

And, lastly, calculate the average of `avg_width`, and save the result.

After that, the curtain moves to the next row in `selected_DF`, and so on.

So far I somehow managed to obtain what I want with this code:

```
val main_DF = spark.read.parquet("hdfs_path_here")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("main_DF")
val selected_DF = spark.read.parquet("hdfs_path_here").collect.par //parallelized array
val final_result_array = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Array[Double]] //for final result

selected_DF.foreach{x => 
    val temp = x.split(',')
    val start_index = temp(1)
    val end_index = temp(2)

    //obtain peak_start and peak_end (START)
    val temp_df_1 = spark.sql( " (SELECT index, width, height FROM main_DF WHERE width > 25 index BETWEEN " + start_index + " AND " + end_index + ")")

    val temp_df_2 = temp_df_1.withColumn("next_index", lead(temp_df("index"), 1).over(window_spec) ).withColumn("previous_index", lag(temp_df("index"), 1).over(window_spec) )

    val temp_df_3 = temp_df_2.withColumn("rear_gap", temp_df_2.col("index") - temp_df_2.col("previous_index") ).withColumn("front_gap", temp_df_2.col("next_index") - temp_df_2.col("index") )

    val temp_df_4 = temp_df_3.filter("front_gap > 9 or rear_gap > 9")

    val temp_df_5 = temp_df_4.withColumn("next_front_gap", lead(temp_df_4("front_gap"), 1).over(window_spec) ).withColumn("next_front_gap_index", lead(temp_df_4("index"), 1).over(window_spec) )

    val temp_df_6 = temp_df_5.filter("rear_gap > 9 and next_front_gap > 9").sort("index")
    //obtain peak_start and peak_end (END)

    val peak_DF = temp_df_6.select("index" , "next_front_gap_index").toDF("peak_start", "peak_end").collect

    val peak_DF_temp = peak_DF.map { y =>
        spark.sql( " (SELECT avg(width) as avg_width FROM main_DF WHERE index BETWEEN " + y(0) + " AND " + y(1) + ")")
    }

    val peak_DF_summary = peak_DF_temp.reduceLeft( (dfa, dfb) => dfa.unionAll(dfb) )

    val avg_width = peak_DF_summary.agg(mean("avg_width")).as[(Double)].first

    final_result_array += avg_width._1
}
spark.catalog.dropTempView("main_DF")
```

([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900556/spark-scala-execute-dataframe-within-for-loop/42908643))

The problem is, the code can only run until around halfway (after 20-30 iterations) until it crashed and give out `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. It runs okay when I ran the iterations 1-by-1, though.

So my questions are:

1. How can there be insufficient memory? I thought the reason should be
   accumulated usage of memory, so I add `.unpersist()` for every
   dataframe inside `foreach` loop (even though I do no `.persist()`) to no avail.
   But then, every memory consumption should be reset along with
   re-initiation of variables when we enter new iteration in `foreach`
   loop, no?
2. Is there any efficient way to do this kind of calculation? I am
   doing nested-loop in Spark and I feel like this is a very
   inefficient way to do this, but so far it's the only way I can get
   result.

I'm using CDH 5.7 with Spark 2.1.0. My cluster has 6 nodes with 32GB memory (each) & 40 cores (total). `main_DF` is based on 30GB parquet file.

Comment: How do you get `peak_end` column in first output?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but I strongly suspect you want a join rather than the nested loops.

Comment: I'm sorry. Let me edit my question here

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I add more details, please check

Comment: @hoyland thanks man, but I think `join` may not be the solution. Basically, from a bunch of raw data, I select the important groups. Then from each important groups, I select the even more important groups, then calculate their average. Hope this explanation helps =)